# How can I reconnect a 3-way switch circuit and restore power to downstream outlets?

Tags: wiring

I had an attic fan hooked up to a 3 way switch...It seems the power went into Switch A to the Fan, then out of Fan to Switch B. I recently had the Fan removed to install an Attic Stairs by a handyman, who did not re hook up the electric, This has caused me to also lose power to some outlets down the line on the same breaker.

I currently have the two cables (coming/going from/to each switch) in the attic. Each has Black, White, Red and Ground. The one coming from Switch A, is Hot on the Black. Is there a way to connect them to complete the circuit so I can complete the circuit and recover power in the other outlets in the chain?

Comment: What you describe makes sense for the switches, but not for the outlets. You can't really have downstream outlets on a 3-way switch situation unless they split off the same point where power comes in for the switches.

Comment: Were either of the switch boxes disconnected, or just the fan box?

Comment: Just the fan box.....I am clearly not great with electric but I was surprised also that  I would lose the other outlets.....I was thinking that they must split off from the same point, though I didnt pull the switch to see....and the fact that the circuit is broken now is why I am having issue

Comment: Old House with alot of crazy wiring schemes

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved?